# Edit points on text in powerpoint

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, microsoft-powerpoint-2010

Years ago, on the older versions of powerpoint it was relatively easy to take a text box with some text in whatever font you wanted, and easily get it to 'break down' into a shape you could 'edit points' of; and quickly use this as a starting point for whatever crazy modifications you wanted...

So now - over a decade later, I'm using powerpoint 2010 and i'm having a helluva time getting text to become a freeform object. Any ideas? I tried the trick with 'paste special' as metadata; which seems to take on many aspects of freeform objects, but I still can't edit points.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably thinking of some other software. PowerPoint has never been able to do this, though CorelDraw, Adobe Illustrator have since forever.

There's a slightly out-of-box trick in PowerPoint 2013 that allows this.  I can't recall the step-by-step offhand right now, but will work it out if you're interested.  It won't work in PPT 2010 or prior versions though.